# "Pride oneself in" vs "Pride oneself on"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> She prides herself ***in/on*** her ability to spot a shoplifter.
>
> I pride myself ***in/on*** my ability to find compromises.

Is there any difference between two phrasal verbs "Pride oneself in" and "Pride oneself on" ?

Comment: The idiomatic standards are *I **take** pride **in** my honesty* and *I pride myself **on** my honesty*. Reversing those preposition usages will sound odd to any native speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought as you do, but a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i+pride+myself+in%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) shook me from my complacency. Looks like **_in_** has lots of adherents.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: You have to be *extra* careful about Google's "guesstimates" when you search for text strings containing prepositions like that (the estimate is often unduly skewed by how common the preposition is *in general*, not just in the exact specified context). But check out [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+pride+myself+in%2CI+pride+myself+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20pride%20myself%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20pride%20myself%20on%3B%2Cc0) (I don't think NGrams suffer from that flaw).

Comment: @F⚡︎F Note that my search is for the enquoted phrase! This should eliminate that error in result. I ran the ngram, and not surprisingly the strong preference is **on.** But I _was_ surprised at the robust and relatively constant showing of **in,** because my ear, like yours, hears it as odd. It's easy to understand why some speakers follow the natural progression from _take pride in_ to _pride one's self in._ The striking thing about the ngram is the reversal at ~1840.

Answer (score 3):

In general, English idiomatic expressions like this one require a specific preposition in the phrase.  There's no real rule to this, you just have to memorize it.  In this case to my ear the correct phrase is "pride myself **on**".  "Pride myself **in**" doesn't sound right, and I can't recall ever hearing it used.

See also the following related [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7607/which-is-the-correct-preposition-for-the-end-of-pride-myself-is-it-on-at).

Comment: I think there's maybe a *bit* of a "rule" in that you can also for example ***congratulate** [yourself or another] **on** [some achievement]*, but we use ***in*** with things like ***take** comfort **in** [something comforting]*. Maybe I'm imagining things, but it seems to me that to at least some extent, ***on*** works in more "active" contexts (where you're ***in*** control, confusingly enough! :), whereas ***in*** works in more "passive" contexts (the situation affects you, rather than you affecting/defining the situation).

Comment: Ok -- but as a counter-example, why do we we "give up" when we surrender?  Why not "give down" since we're effectively supplicating ourselves before the victor?   How come we "get on" a train when we're stepping *inside* it?   But then we "get in" a car!   This is why I advise memorization, because it's not always logical.

Comment: Anyway, relevant "Japlish" sign seen in a railway station:  "Please do not run into the train."  Good advice.

Comment: Trains are bigger than cars, and they usually have one or more steps to get you up to the "floor level" - ***on*** which you can walk. If we take a more "intermediate" noun like an old-time western stagecoach I imagine usage would be much more evenly divided between whether you get in or on it (with a significant contextual element depending on whether you're interested in being "inside = out of the weather" or on a  conveyance that will take you somewhere (as still applies with *I'm **in/on** the bus*).

Answer (score 0):

You take pride in something, therefore you pride yourself 'in' something. It may be common, but priding yourself on something makes no sense to me as a 30-year editor and writer in Australian and UK contexts.

Comment: As an equally experienced (if not more so, in years, at least, LOL) and from a Canadian context, I have to question your position, Clive.
Why? Because we compliment someone on doing the right thing, achieving excellence, etc, and in essence when we "take pride", we are complimenting ourselves, so on that basis for example, why CAN'T we "Take pride on being a good father"?
Also, a variable that might suggest the use of the "on" choice would be a situation where there's an EVENT or an OCCASION marking a point in time, such as "He prided himself on (or, "upon") his graduation from law school.